# Insert data to database on condition PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i inserting data to database using condition ?like the one i'm having now..the condition is..if value is null,then insert data1...else,if value is inserted,then insert data 2...here's is the example of the code..

```
$insert1 = array(
                'number' => $number,
                'value' => $value,
                'car_id' => $car_id,
                );
$insert2 = array(
                'number' => $number,
                'value' => $value,
                'status' => 1,
                );
    if('car_id'== NULL) <-----(This is the problem)
     {
       $this->db->insert('tbl_a',$insert2);
     }else
     {
       $this->db->insert('tbl_a',$insert1);
     }
```

what the condition i should put on case like that ? thank you for any helps...

Comment: Doing comparison on NULL will not work. you need to use is_null($car_id) function instead.

Comment: hmm...so it should be like ...if(is_null($car_id)){.....} ? @Dimi

Comment: yes. or isset($car_id) . or just strlen($car_id)>0. whichever one works best.

Comment: i will try that code..i'll let you know when the code works @Dimi,Thanks btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$insert1 = array(
                'number' => $number,
                'value' => $value,
                'car_id' => $car_id,
                );
$insert2 = array(
                'number' => $number,
                'value' => $value,
                'status' => 1,
                );
    if($car_id !== NULL) <-----(see here)
     {
       $this->db->insert('tbl_a',$insert1); (change here too )
     }else
     {
       $this->db->insert('tbl_a',$insert2);(change here too )
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `isset($insert1['car_id'])` to check whether the `car_id` has value or not.

```
$insert1 = array(
                'number' => $number,
                'value' => $value,
                'car_id' => $car_id,
                );
$insert2 = array(
                'number' => $number,
                'value' => $value,
                'status' => 1,
                );
    if(isset($insert1['car_id'])) //see here
     {
       $this->db->insert('tbl_a',$insert2);
     }else
     {
       $this->db->insert('tbl_a',$insert1);
     }
```

Comment: i got an Error says "You must use the "set" method to update an entry"

Comment: i'm inserting the data...i already tried many things...but it's always running the Else Condition instead of If

Comment: i've done it.the select value cannot be null..it has to be at least 1 value...so i set if($car_id == "0"){....}else{...}

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing your null check properly.

Try, 
If(is_null($car_id) && strlen($car_id) ==0)
//insert 1
Else
//insert two